# Residue calculation for simple pole is coming different from two approaches.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{z^{4}+9z^{2}}$$

For a simple pole alternate formula : $$\operatorname{Res}((),) = \frac{()}{′()}$$
While the general formula for finding residue still holds.

The answer is coming very different for simple pole $z=3i$ from the general residue formula and the alternate formula.

I got e^3i / -36+54i and e^3i / 54i respectively.

Same issue with many problems.

Are there any limitations to the alternate formula? if so please state that.

Comment: What did you find by using the two formulas?

Comment: e^3i / -36+54i and e^3i / 54i respectively.

Comment: Did you read my answer below? Finally, have you understood what you did wrong?

Comment: ya thanks, calculation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second value is the correct one.

General formula: we should evaluate
$$\lim_{z\to 3i}\frac{e^{z}(z-3i)}{z^{4}+9z^{2}}=\lim_{z\to 3i}\frac{e^{z}}{z^2(z+3i)}=\frac{e^{3i}}{(3i)^{3}+(3i)^{3}}=\frac{e^{3i}}{-54i}=\frac{ie^{3i}}{54}$$
where $z^{4}+9z^{2}=z^2(z+3i)(z-3i)$.

Second formula with $P(z)=e^z$ and $Q(z)=z^{4}+9z^{2}$:
$$\operatorname{Res}((),3i) = \frac{P(3i)}{Q'(3i)}=\frac{e^{3i}}{4(3i)^{3}+18(3i)}=\frac{e^{3i}}{-54i}=\frac{ie^{3i}}{54}$$